# How to speed up this loop in google app scipts?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Befor anything I would like to say I know that batch functions are more efficient in updating spreadsheets, however here I am trying to make a list full of alternating colours and although I am updating the sheet with `range.setBackgrounds()` It's still taking way too long, it there a way I can optimise this?

```
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B11:G30");
  var background = [];
  var startRow = range.getRow();
  var maxRows = range.getRow() + range.getNumRows()
  
  for (row = startRow; row < maxRows ; row++) {
    if (row % 2 == 1) {
      var colour = ["#D9D9D9", "#D9D9D9", "#D9D9D9", "#D9D9D9", "#D9D9D9", "#D9D9D9"];
    }
    else {
      var colour = ["#FFFFFF", "#FFFFFF", "#FFFFFF", "#FFFFFF", "#FFFFFF", "#FFFFFF"];
    }
    background.push(colour);
  }
  range.setBackgrounds(background);
```

Comment: Your range is undefined.  Please provide [mcve]  Please pay attention to reproducible aspect

Comment: Does it work now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function alternateColors() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const sr=2;
  const rg=sh.getRange(sr,1,sh.getLastRow()-sr+1,sh.getLastColumn());
  let cA=rg.getBackgrounds();
  cA.forEach(function(r,i){
    r.forEach(function(c,j){
      if(i%2==1) {
        cA[i][j]='#d9d9d9';
      }else{
        cA[i][j]='#ffffff';
      }
    });
  });
  rg.setBackgrounds(cA); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, runs way faster than my origional, however sometimes it doesn't run?

Comment: How are you running it?

Comment: What do you mean by ```it doesnt run```? Is it returning any error?

Comment: I put it in an awkward spot and so it was generating the array but it wasnt updating the background, I just had to restructure my code and now the project is finished

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative version of [Cooper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65163449/11225291), so please don't unaccept his answer.

But this will surely give you some extra boost in performance:

```
function alternateColors() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const sr=2;
  const rg=sh.getRange(sr,1,sh.getLastRow()-sr+1,sh.getLastColumn());
  let cA=rg.getBackgrounds();
  cA=cA.map((r,i)=>Array(r.length).fill([i%2==1?'#d9d9d9':'#ffffff']).flat());
  rg.setBackgrounds(cA); 
}
```

The idea is that by using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of two `forEach` loops and element wise assignment operations you will get better performance especially if the input matrix is large.

Comment: Feel free to use Marios answer.  I only share what I know and I'm here more to learn than to teach.